OOM Kill occurs during loadtxoutset execution
I tried to load a snapshot using the assumeutxo feature provided in Bitcoin Core v28.0. I ran loadtxoutset during IBD after the block headers were synced.
But every time my login session gets killed after the following log:
..
2024-10-07T05:14:26Z FlushSnapshotToDisk: flushing coins cache (403 MB) started
...
2024-10-07T05:18:16Z FlushSnapshotToDisk: completed (230130.94ms)
...
2024-10-07T05:18:17Z FlushSnapshotToDisk: saving snapshot chainstate (45 MB) started
...
2024-10-07T05:22:01Z FlushSnapshotToDisk: completed (224537.77ms)
...

Checking the syslog, it appears that the process is being killed by oom.
2024-10-07T14:22:47.365074+09:00 FRONTIER systemd[3115]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
2024-10-07T14:22:47.366504+09:00 FRONTIER systemd[3115]: vte-spawn-4785ea6e-8c4a-44d0-80aa-72e36fb7107a.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
2024-10-07T14:22:47.366578+09:00 FRONTIER systemd[3115]: vte-spawn-4785ea6e-8c4a-44d0-80aa-72e36fb7107a.scope: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
2024-10-07T14:22:47.366672+09:00 FRONTIER systemd[3115]: vte-spawn-4785ea6e-8c4a-44d0-80aa-72e36fb7107a.scope: Consumed 2h 7min 57.285s CPU time, 46.4G memory peak, 0B memory swap peak.

Is this an issue with Bitcoin Core? and is there a way to work around this?
The snapshots are taken from the link below:
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:596c26cc709e213fdfec997183ff67067241440c&dn=utxo-840000.dat&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.bitcoin.sprovoost.nl%3A6969
My environment is Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.

What dbcache setting do you have?

@PieterWuille I haven't explicitly set it, so it's just the default setting.
